# S3 boto3 delete files except a specific file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Probably this is just a newbie question.

I have a python code using boto3 sdk and i need to delete all files from an s3 bucket except one file.

The issue is that the user is updating this S3 bucket and places some files into some folders. After i copy those files i need to delete them, hence the issue here is that the folders are deleted as well, since there is no concept of folders on Cloud Providers. I need to keep the "folder" structure intact. I was thinking of placing a dummy file inside each "folder" and exclude that file from deletion.

Is this something doable?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the "folder" structure intact?

Comment: Because they are being update manually by a user.  If i delete the folders then he will have to recreate the folders manually which would be cumbersome.

Comment: Note that there's typically no need for folders in S3. You don't need a folder in order to be able to upload a file. You just upload the file with the desired key and any new, intermediate folder hierarchy is implicit.

Comment: Maybe i did not explained better my use case. I have to sync some files from that S3 to GCS in an automatic way(Python, rsync etc), so the files that are uploaded by an end user are always going to reside in that "folder structure", i need that structure because each folder from S3 maps to a bucket in GCS. After the files have been moved i need to delete them from S3( hence here resides the issue) but keep the folder so that on the next day the user can upload other files into those folders. I hope i explained a little bit better this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a zero-byte object with the same name as the folder you want ending in a `/`, it will show up as an empty folder in the AWS Console, and other tools that enumerate objects delimited by prefix will see the prefix in their list of common prefixes:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket='example-bucket', Key='example/folder/', Body=b'')
```

Then, as you enumerate the list of objects to delete them, ignore any object that ends in a `/`, since this will just be the markers you're using for folders:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='example-bucket', Prefix='example/folder/')
for cur in resp['Contents']:
    if cur['Key'].endswith('/'):
        print("Ignoring folder marker: " + cur['Key'])
    else:
        print("Should delete object: " + cur['Key'])
        # TODO: Delete this object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in files_in_bucket:
    if file.name != file_name_to_keep:
        file.delete()
```

Could follow this sort of logic in your script?